# Strings are equal, but if-statement doesn't trigger

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

I'm trying to construct my own expressions evaluator based on the Shunting-yard algorithm. I'm having difficulty adding `String` objects to the stack I have though. My code just skips over these lines every time, even when the condition is met. Any suggestions? I have the `operatorStack` declared as:

```
Stack operatorStack = new Stack();
```

I'm thinking that it has something to do with my if statement. I've tested it with the Eclipse debugger and when the `currentChar` variable shows as `"("` it still skips over the push to the stack.

Here is the excerpt in question:

```
int count = 0;
String currentChar=new String();

//While loop to test for the conditions stated in the Shunting-yard algorithm.
while (count<=temp.length()) {

    currentChar = temp.substring(count, count+1);
    if(currentChar == "(")
        operatorStack.push(currentChar);

    if(expressionEval(currentChar) instanceof Integer)
        outputQueue.offer((Integer)expressionEval(currentChar));

    if(currentChar == "+" || 
               currentChar == "-" || 
               currentChar == "<" || 
               currentChar == "?") {

        while(operatorStack.peek() == "+" || 
                          operatorStack.peek() == "-" || 
                          operatorStack.peek() == "<" || 
                          operatorStack.peek() == "?") {
            outputQueue.offer((Integer)operatorStack.peek());
            operatorStack.pop();
        }

        operatorStack.push(currentChar);
    }
```

Comment: NetBeans gives me a warning when I try to compare strings using `==`, doesn't Eclipse, or are you ignoring it?

Comment: You can probably change `String currentChar=new String();` to `String currentChar;`. The `=new String()` doesn't serve any purpose, based on the given excerpt. ... or just declare it where you assign it - `String currentChar = temp.substring(count, count+1);`

Comment: I knew the duplicate of this question even before reading it ..... sad, but true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing Strings using "==" instead of "equals".
The comparison condition is never met.

Also you should consider using "char" instead of "String" when taking a peek at single characters, using myString.charAt(count) (for example).

--- this is considering you are trying this in Java.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for not searching for the dupe more diligently everyone.